# Blower motor runs won't shut off no heat

Tags: hvac

My furnace is set at 72, my house is 64. I have no heat, and when I turn the thermostat off, it continually runs.
When I'm running the air conditioner, it blows heat.
What is a possible cause?

Comment: Welcome to SE. More information, please. Is this a new or older home? What's the make and model of the hardware components? Did you recently have any work done? Has it worked properly in the recent past? (Edit your question to clarify--don't add new information in comments.)

Comment: What type of system is it, heat pump, oil, propane, natural gas? Has the thermostat, circuit board, or fan center if oil been changed recently? Do you have multiple zones and a zone control has been replaced? Could be a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

One or more limits are open.  You'll have to determine which one is open, figure out why it's open, and then fix whatever's causing it to be open.

If you look at the control board in the furnace/air handler, you may see a blinking light (or two). Count the number of blinks in the pattern, and compare it to the manufacturer's documentation. This will often point you in the direction of the problem.

If there are no diagnostic lights, then you'll have to check each limit until you locate the open one. If you don't have the tools or knowledge to work on HVAC equipment, it may be time to contact a local HVAC company.